# Angular 7 Reactive Form Array - Calculate Form values

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I have been creating a billing application where I will be capturing item name and price. I want to give discount for the item so I will be having discount in percentage and discount in dollar text boxes. In some cases, either I can enter discount in percentage or discount in dollar values so I want to display both of the them at run time. For example, if I enter discount in dollar then I have to display value in discount in percentage. Can you please help me to solve the requirement?

I have created a sample application using Stackblitz with Angular and reactive forms - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hayn68-yjqorz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td class="form-group">
      <input #perc type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="discountInPercentage" 
      (change)="percChanged(i, perc.value)">
</td>
```

TS

```
percChanged(i, val){
    this.itemForm.value.items[i].discountInDollar = this.itemForm.value.items[i].rate/100*val;
    this.itemForm.controls['items'].setValue(this.itemForm.value.items);
    console.log(this.itemForm.value.items[i].discountInDollar);
}
```

Change the %Discount value and you should see the output. [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hayn68-m6deot)

Comment: Thank you @ala. Can you please suggest on updating the value in UI. I had *formControlName="discountInDollar"* in the template but the value in not getting updated after percChanged method set the value _this.itemForm.value.items[i].discountInDollar_. Updated stackblitz URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hayn68-ovpgar

Comment: a work around would be to add this `this.itemForm.controls['items'].setValue(this.itemForm.value.items);` to your percChanged, https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hayn68-m6deot

Comment: I edited my answer, kindly upvote and mark as solved if that solved your issue.